# How to use a variable in place of file in templatefile function?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to use a string variable in place of the filename in the templatefile function call?

https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

templatefile(path, vars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `path` can be a variable:

```
templatefile(var.mytemplate, vars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have used and it worked:

main.tf

```
variable "templatefile" {
    default = "filter.tftpl"
  
}

resource "local_file" "one" {
    content  = templatefile("${path.module}/${var.templatefile}", { response_code = local.file_one_response_code })
    filename = "${path.module}/one"
}

resource "local_file" "two" {
    content  = templatefile("${path.module}/${var.templatefile}", { response_code = local.file_two_response_code })
    filename = "${path.module}/two"
}
```

filter.tftpl

```
metric.type="loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count" AND
metric.label.response_code_class="${response_code}" AND
resource.type="https_lb_rule" AND
resource.label.url_map_name = "myurlname"
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  file_one_response_code = "400"
  file_two_response_code = "500"
}
```